# wait for setTImeout in page.evaluate puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using this code

```
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    for (var x = 0, ln = list.length; x < ln; x++) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        console.log('scrolling');
        await page.evaluate(() => {
          window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
        });
      }, x * 2000);
    }
    resolve();
  });
```

how do I resolve when all the setTimeouts are over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setTimeout, you can use the built-in function of puppeteer:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(x * 2000);
```